# Cleaner way to bind to a DependencyProperty of the parent UserControl from a child control

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have a custom UserControl with a custom DependencyProperty.  To paint a better picture of how I'm using this, the UserControl is the left navigation indicator in a wizard-like control.  The left nav control exists inside of each of the controls that represent a step in the wizard.  Inside of the left nav control, I am toggling visibility and setting visual properties of several child controls with a few converters with code similar to the following.  I can't use a simple style selector or style-selecting converter because the entire structure of each row in my StackPanel is different if the item is selected or not.

This is a ton of code to be repeating all over my control to bind to a single custom property.  Is there a shorter form version of the following or a cleaner way to implement this?

```
<Polygon
    Visibility="{Binding
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
    AncestorType=UserControl},
    Path=Selected,
    Converter={StaticResource myCustomConverter},
    ConverterParameter='Expected String'}">
...
```

The parent views supply a single property to customize the child control:

```
    <!-- Left Column -->
    <views:LeftNavControl Selected="Item to Select..." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you could do, but I would not describe them as neither a cleaner/shorter way to implement it. They are fairy easy to implement if you are using a `MVVM` approach.

The first thing you could do is getting rid of the `RelativeSource/AncestorType` in your bindings to find the location of the bound property.
If both/all your controls (it's not clear how many controls you use) would share the same viewmodel you could bound the same viewmodel property to `views:LeftNavControl.Selected`, and to all of your toggled visibility controls.

The second thing you could do, is a more radical approach that would clean your xaml, and it will also make your `myCustomConverter` obsolete, but will move some of the business logic in your viewmodel. This works best in case you have a multitude of `Polygons`/other controls that need visibility toggle.
You could have a `StepXVisiblity` property in your viewmodel, and you could calculate it every time `views:LeftNavControl.Selected` changes and your Polygon(s) xaml will look like:

```
<Polygon Visibility="{Binding StepXVisiblity}">
```

A simple example of the above explanation would be:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Step, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Text="One" Visibility="{Binding StepOneVisible}" />
    <TextBlock Text="One" Visibility="{Binding StepOneVisible}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Two" Visibility="{Binding StepTwoVisible}" />
    <TextBlock Text="Two" Visibility="{Binding StepTwoVisible}" />
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
public class MyVM : DomainBase
{
    private int step;

    public int Step
    {
        get 
        { 
            return step; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            step = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Step");
            OnPropertyChanged("StepOneVisible");
            OnPropertyChanged("StepTwoVisible");
        }
    }

    public Visibility StepOneVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return step == 1 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public Visibility StepTwoVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return step == 2 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using a very lightweight MVVM implementation (no framework, just wrote some VM base classes and helpers), but I wasn't backing this control by a VM just yet because I didn't need it for anything else in the control.  That's definitely the logical way to go about this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is to create your own binding class that derives from the base one (which itself is a markup extension) and sets all of those properties to the defaults you normally use. That way you will only have to specify the things that aren't default.

Answer (score 0):

First, since you said something along the lines of Navigation panel, you might want to think about using something like a listview or a listbox and templating your items while binded to a collection in your view model. But, since I don't know the scope of your Nav control, I will assume that your Nav control doesn't exactly fit this scheme.

I will suggest using Attached Properties to achieve what you described as setting multiple properties based on single parent property. Consider the following as pseudo-code since I haven't tested it:

```
    public class MagicHelper
    {
        #region Super Property


        public static readonly DependencyProperty SuperProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Super", typeof(SecretType), typeof(MagicHelper)
                new PropertyMetadata(-1, SuperChanged));

        // Get
        public static SecretType GetSuper(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (SecretType)obj.GetValue(SuperProperty);
        }

        // Set
        public static void SetSuper(DependencyObject obj, SecretType value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SuperProperty, value);
        }

        // Change Event - make stuff happen here
        public static void SuperChanged(
            DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

// I am using Polygon here for example but you could use a base class that might cover all your controls
            if (!(obj is Polygon))
                return;


            Polygon pGon = (Polygon)obj;

        // do your thing to pGon here with e.NewValue
        var mySecretInstance = e.NewValue as SecretType;

        if (mySecretInstance.frap)
        {
        pGon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        pGon.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }

...
...

        }

}
```

and the XAML goes something like this

```
<UserControl Name="thisControl" 
xmlns:local="yourLibrary">
<Polygon local:MagicHelper.Super="{Binding ElementName=thisControl, Path=Selected"/>
...
```

m